# Writing JSON data to a JSON file and reading using FS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js, fs

Basically I have code in which it adds json data to a specific json file that I own. The code itself is working, but I wanted it to be implemented inside the table in the json file. I also wanted to be able to read the information in the json file(Specifically see what ids it has, if message.author has that id, and then return a message saying it's banned along with the reason)

Note: The purpose of this code is to be used on the Discord platform, using the discord.js library.

JSON File:

```json
{
    "bans": [
        {
        "id": "218931839123128",
        "reason": "yes"
    },
    {
        "id": "273618444",
        "reason": "no"
    }
]
}
```

Code:

```js
        let format = {
                "id": target, //args[0]
                "reason": reason //args[1]
        }

fs.appendFile('banlist.json', JSON.stringify(format), function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  message.channel.send("Added.")
  console.log('Saved!');
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want to develop.

Comment: this is a ban system to check if the message.author have this id. If have, the bot will return a message with the reason why he cant use the command. I created a command like "banfrombot", and i put the id(args[0]) and the reason(args[1]), so i want to write to json file this in the bans table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to append an object to an array in a JSON file, you may need to do the following:

1. Read the JSON file
2. Parse the JSON file into JavaScript objects
3. Add your object to the specified array
4. Stringify your object into a JSON string
5. Write the JSON file

[`fs.appendFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_path_data_options_callback) adds data to the end of a file and is probably not what you are looking for.

Here is an example of what working code could look like:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const dataToAdd = {
  id: "target",
  reason: "reason"
};

// Read the JSON file
const JSONString = fs.readFileSync("./banlist.json", "utf8");

// Parse the JSON file
const JSData = JSON.parse(JSONString);

// Add object to the array
JSData.push(dataToAdd);

// Stringify the data
const newJSONString = JSON.stringify(JSData, null, 2);

// Write the file
fs.writeFileSync("./banlist.json", newJSONString);
```

To compare data in your JSON file and notify that the user is banned:

1. Read the JSON
2. Parse the JSON
3. Using some kind of algorithm or loop, check and compare the data
4. If the data matches, output that the user is banned

Comment: I tried this method but its returning "JSData.push is not a function". How can i solve this?

Comment: Looking at the JSON data you provided, it looks like the list is at `JSDATA.bans`, so probably `JSDATA.bans.push(...)` should work.